# How to plot a bar graph in R using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image]

> I'm trying to plot this graph using R but dont know how.

[image]

> Screenshot of the dataset that I'm  using

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't provide the dataset, but you could do something like that

```
# packages ----------------------------------------------------------------

library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

# data --------------------------------------------------------------------

#load your data first
#
#

#get just the last observation for each location
dataset2 <- dataset %>% 
  group_by(location) %>% 
  slice_tail() %>% 
  ungroup()

# plot --------------------------------------------------------------------

dataset2 %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = continent, y = total_deaths))+
  geom_bar()
```